# Bitwise AND and order of operations in C/C++

Tags: c++

I'm currently dissecting through the ol' Doom engine source code, and came across an interesting line:

```
counter = (++counter)&(MAX_VALUE-1);
```

Looks like a way to increment a counter without going over a certain number, but I have a tricky time doing bitwise operations in my head so I whipped up a quick console project to try this out, and lo and behold, it works beautifully. I deduce the above way is more efficient than an if() statement, especially if the code is executed rapidly, for example, within a loop, where performance within a real-time game is crucial. What I'm trying to figure out is the order of operations the compiler uses to execute this line. If the increment '++' operator is placed after the 'counter', it will always remain zero. It only works if the increment is used as a prefix ("++counter"), but even still, if I write it out with pen and paper, I get the arbitrary result of the bitwise AND operation, not a counter that increments. It seems the bitwise operation is calculated, and THEN the increment is performed, but I'm stumped figuring out why, any ideas?

Comment: That code demonstrates undefined behavior and should not be emulated. The correct line is `counter = (counter + 1)^(MAX_VALUE-1);`.

Comment: @RaymondChen xor? really? why is anding ub? the counter+1 makes sense though as the evaluation order is not specified.

Comment: @vidstige It was not the `AND` that caused the ub, it was the `++`

Comment: Sorry, typo. Should have been `counter = (counter + 1)&(MAX_VALUE-1);` The point is that the `++` and the `=` result in two writes to the same variable between sequence points, which is UB.

Comment: You are right to be stumped, because it really doesn't work. Updating `counter` twice in the same expression is not allowed by the language. The Doom engine might do things that worked on their compiler, but isn't portable.

Comment: Hi. I upvoted all your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the parentheses have higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than operator `++` or bitwise `AND` (operator `&`), there are no defined [sequence points](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) in your right-hand side. So your code exhibits undefined behavior.

If you remove the operator`++` what this is intending to do is

```
(counter + 1)&(MAX_VALUE-1);
```

If you consider `MAX_VALUE` to be `32` then `MAX_VALUE-1` in binary is

```
11111
```

So if you have a larger value than that and use `&` any bits left of bit 5 (from the right) will be cleared

```
0000011111   // assume this is MAX_VALUE - 1 
1100110110   // assume this is counter + 1
__________
0000010110
```

The result would be `true` if any of the bits less than or equal to `MAX_VALUE - 1` were `1`.

Answer (score 0):

The formula

```
counter = (++counter)&(MAX_VALUE-1);
```

has undefined behaviour, see CoryKramer's answer.

The formula

```
counter = (counter + 1)&(MAX_VALUE - 1);
```

works only for MAX_VALUEs that are equal to a power of 2. Only then the value `MAX_VALUE - 1` has this form in binary:

```
000...000111...111
```

When such a value is used in a AND operation, it "truncates" the higher bits of the other value, and has the effect of wrapping around when the other value reaches MAX_VALUE.

I think the normal modulo operation is just as fast on modern hardware, and does not have the restriction mentionend above:

```
counter = (counter + 1)%MAX_VALUE;
```